# MVC Bundling and Minification Bad URL

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have a few websites that use the same code base, but look different. On one of the websites, the CSS bundle gets a 404 error, but the other sites don't have this issue. I am using System.Web.Mvc version 5.2.3. I have BundleTable.EnableOptimizations set to true. Here is what the bundle looks like.

```
var cssName = GetConfigurationValue("StyleSheetName");
var cssBundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/CSS").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                    string.Format("~/css/{0}.css", cssName));
bundles.Add(cssBundle);
```

The website that is working has the url as:

```
Content/CSS?v=ZoOnxTYIFYeSZONlc0yICzLMKodsPREd6rdpEoLclcw1
```

The website that is not working has the url as:

```
Content/CSS?v=UOFPTVfEQiXwaJ5YQDpCS3Y3CrYsXvqTD--Dqmd6hxo1
```

If I open the url directly and remove the "--", I get the css back.Could this just be a random error with the version hash? The broken website was working before, but just started having issues.

EDIT:
I was able to get it working by modifying the css a little bit, so that it would regenerate the hash, but how can I make sure that this doesn't happen again?